# Is it possible to decline all friend requests?

Tags: diablo-iii, battle.net

As title says: is it possible to decline all friend requests in a few clicks?

Currently I have 70+ requests and all of them are from bots, offering me in-game-gold and items. That's kinda frustrating.

Comment: I haven't found a way either and its super annoying.  I'm in the same situation.  I don't even keep that tab open anymore because of it.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that if you have Starcraft 2 on your battlenet account,you can log in there and report/delete those requests much faster.You can just click like maniac in one spot since it doesn't have the 2nd confirmation prompt like Diablo 3 does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way is to max your friends list out so you can't get more requests. The max is 100. So get 100 friends on there and just delete one when you want to add one. Wish there was another way as it's annoying.

The only other way is to get a WoW account and use the addon BadBoy to auto decline them all while in WoW.

source: http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/1ugcbg/anyone_know_how_to_stop_the_spam_of_pvpbank/

Comment: Given that you can log into WoW at low levels for free, that isn't the worst solution in the world... (It is, of course, a whole lot bandwidth and storage space to cope with a nuisance however.)